# Swift : Background Color fading animation (SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, swift, background, sprite-kit, fade

I'm creating a game, the background color is white to begin with hence:

```
self.backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
```

So when the game initiates white is the background. I have a scoring system, so essentially I want the colors to change when a certain score is reached hence:

```
if score < 100{
            enemy.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(mainBall.position, duration:3))  
        }
        else if score >= 100 && score < 200{
            enemy.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(mainBall.position, duration:2.5))
            self.backgroundColor = SKColor.purpleColor()
        }
        else if score >= 200 && score < 300{
            enemy.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(mainBall.position, duration:2))
            self.backgroundColor = SKColor.greenColor()
        }
```

however, this method is very clunky and looks pretty awful if I'm honest. Everything in my game is fluid and contains fades when being removed from the scene using:

```
livesLabel.runAction(SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.5))
```

But I am unsure as to how I would proceed to do this with the background color. If I use the above example with backgroundColor such as

```
self.backgroundColor = SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(SKColor.purpleColor())
```

I get the error "Cannot invoke 'fadeInWithDuration' with an argument list of type '(UIColor)'"

Note: I understand completely that attempting to assign the background color to an animation is silly. But I put that code in there to try get my problem across

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To smoothly transition from the current background color to a different color, use the `colorizeWithColor` `SKAction`. Here's an example...

```
runAction(SKAction.colorizeWithColor(SKColor.purpleColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 2.0))
```

Answer (score 2):

Put this code in your viewDidLoad method and see if it is what you are looking for

```
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 1.0, options: nil, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    }, completion: nil)
```

If this is what you are looking for do something like

```
    if (score < 100){
        enemy.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(mainBall.position, duration:3))  
    }
    else if (score >= 100 && score < 200){
        enemy.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(mainBall.position, duration:2.5))
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
           self.backgroundColor = SKColor.purpleColor()
       })
    }
    else if (score >= 200 && score < 300){
        enemy.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(mainBall.position, duration:2))
         UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
           self.backgroundColor = SKColor.greenColor()
    })
    }`
```

Comment: Hi Colin, I'm looking for a fade in. not a delay. Thank you though

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your if statements to `override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval)` (this method gets called every frame).

Also, I'd suggest you remove the () after the if statement as they are redundant, the same goes with the self before backgroundColor.

Comment: my if statement was inside that function, also thanks for the pointers but your comment hasn't helped my situation

Comment: I tried it in a sample project and it worked for me. What you could do is to track 'score' with breakpoints to see if the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: Julia you don't understand my question. The score system is absolutely fine. I'm trying to change the background with an animation, so it fades in basically