# How to gradually (animated) change background color in Spritekit?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, sprite-kit, background-color

**SOLUTIONS I TRIED:**

[Gradually change background color in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32287237/gradually-change-background-color-in-swift)

[Swift : Background Color fading animation (SpriteKit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32211803/swift-background-color-fading-animation-spritekit)

---

**WHAT I CURRENTLY HAVE (not working):**

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate{

    var background = SKSpriteNode()

    var colorizeToRed = SKAction()


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        background = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blueColor(), size: self.frame.size)

        background.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)

        background.zPosition = 15

        colorizeToRed = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(SKColor(red: 90, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 2.0)

        background.runAction(colorizeToRed)

    }

}
```

---

**MY PROBLEM:**

I don't see the background change color. The only time I see it change color is if I set it directly with no animation using `self.backgroundColor = UIColor().aColor`.

EDIT: In fact, I dont'even see the blue background... Something is wrong with my SKSpriteNode, but what ?

---

**QUESTION:**

How to gradually (animated) change background color in Spritekit ?

---

**BEFORE YOU ASK:**

1) YES, I have already tried changing the zPosition in case the SKNode was hidden.

2) YES, I have checked the doc for `SKAction.colorizeWithColor()`.

3) YES, I am almost certain the solution to my problem is very simple (probably some mistake on my part), but what ?

4) YES, I am open to any suggestions telling me the error is somewhere else in my code, but only if you precise where that error might be.

5) NO, I will not post my ENTIRE code here, please ask for specific parts if necessary.

---

Thank you in advance for any help you provide ^^ !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the looks of it, I think you just forgot to add the background to the scene. Try this:

```
addChild(background)
```

If that doesn't help, read on...

If you're just fading in an SKSpriteNode then you can use `SKAction.fadeIn` to fade the node in. Just set its `alpha` to 0 to start and fade it in by doing something like this:

```
background.run(SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(2))
```

Comment: I forgot the addChild... Thank you ^^. I am going to go sleep a bit now -___-

Comment: @Coder1000 Hi man, happened to all, the important thing is to solve. Next time try to debug it with breakpoints and PO to console debug, it save my life many times.